# Error al redireccionar con session start() php

Tags: php, web, session

He creado mi aplicación web con html y php. En local funciona perfecto, sin embargo la página subida me da un problema al hacer login porque después de que redirecciona, la sesión se cierra. Hice una pequeña prueba y esto es lo que resultó:
Redireccion del login

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
Conexion::abrir_conexion();
$validador = new ValidadorLogin($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'], Conexion::obtener_conexion());
if ($validador->obtenerError() === '' && !is_null($validador->obtenerEmail())){
    controlSesion::iniciarSesion(
            $validador->obtenerEmail()->obtenerid(),
            $validador->obtenerEmail()->obtenerNombre(),
            $validador->obtenerEmail()->obtenerApellido(),
            $validador->obtenerEmail()->obtenerEmail(),
            $validador->obtenerEmail()->obtenerPassword());
    Redireccion::redirigir(RUTA_SESION);
}
Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
```

}

Condición de la sesión:

```
if (!controlSesion::sesionIniciada()){
//Redireccion::redirigir(INICIO);
echo 'Sesion No Iniciada';
}else{echo 'Sesion Iniciada';}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente adjunto los codigos al momento de iniciar sesion y de comprobar si la sesion está iniciada:

```
    <?php
   class controlSesion{
    public static function iniciarSesion($idUsuario, $userName, 
    $userLastname, $userEmail, $userPassword){
    if (session_id() ==''){
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['idUsuario']=$idUsuario;
    $_SESSION['userName']=$userName;//cokies
    $_SESSION['userLastname']=$userLastname;
    $_SESSION['userEmail']=$userEmail;
    $_SESSION['userPassword']=$userPassword;
}

public static function cerrarSesion(){
    if (session_id() ==''){
        session_start();
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['idUsuario'])){
        unset($_SESSION['idUsuario']);
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['userName'])){
        unset($_SESSION['userName']);
    }
    session_destroy();//destruye la sesion 
}

public static function sesionIniciada(){
    if (session_id() ==''){
        session_start();
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['idUsuario']) && isset($_SESSION['userName'])){
        return True;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

¿Alguna ayuda o sugerencia para este problema?

Answer (score 1):

en el método sesionIniciada(), si inicias sesión solo con session_start() sin pasar por la función iniciarSesion(), las claves 'idUsuario' y 'username' no estarán en la variable $_SESSION y por tanto siempre dará FALSE.

Comment: ¿Entonces sería algo asi la funcion sesionIniciada?
sesionIniciada($idUsuario, $userName,...){